# $\Bbb Q$ is lowest field of characteristic zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

**Theorem:** Field of characteristic zero contains a subfield that is isomorphic to $ \Bbb Q$; so $\Bbb Q$ is lowest field of characteristic zero.

**Proof:** I did following: let char(K)=0. and
$$ \beta :\Bbb Q \to \Bbb K
$$
$$\frac{a}{b}\to (a1_k)(b1_k)^{-1}
$$
so it becomes bijective homeomorphism. then $\Bbb Q \equiv\beta(\Bbb Q) \le \Bbb K$

now, assume $F \subseteq \Bbb Q $ and char (F)=0. we know there is $F' (subfield)\le F$.
how can I continue?

Comment: You have proven the theorem, right? What are you asking now??

Comment: no I havent. I want to show the second part.

Comment: But your first part defines an isomorphism from Q to F, hence F is isomorphic with Q. Is there something wrong?

Comment: I should point out that **homeomorphism** is an isomorphism if topological spaces. You mean to say a bijection homomorphism.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Even better, since we are in a field-theoretic context, we should just say "isomorphism".

Comment: @awllower No, to be precise (which is what we should be right now, since OP is a beginner in field theory), OP didn't prove that the map $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{K}$ is an isomorphism in the case that $\mathbb{K}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}$. There exist many examples of non-surjective field endomorphisms.

Comment: "I want to show the second part" – then first you should formalize what the second part is asking you to show. Here's a precise way to phrase the second part of the question: "for every field $\mathbb{K}$ of characteristic $0$, there is a unique subfield $\mathbb{F} \leq \mathbb{K}$ such that $\mathbb{F}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @VividD: Please avoid trivial edits to old posts.

Comment: What does the less than or equal to symbol mean in the context of sets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let me point out that using $\Bbb C$ in the context of field theory is probably not a good idea if you're not talking about the complex numbers.

Secondly note that there aren't many ways of defining this embedding really. If $K$ is a field of characteristics zero, and we want $f\colon\Bbb Q\to K$ to be an embedding then $0_\Bbb Q$ has to be $0_K$, and similarly for $1_\Bbb Q$. Now by induction we have that for every natural number $f(n)$ is decided, that is $f(1+1)=f(1)+f(1)$, and so on.

From this we deduce that $f$ is completely determined on $\mathbb Z$ (applying $0_K=f(0_\Bbb Q)=f(n+(-n))=f(n)-f(n)$). And from that we can deduce that $f$ is completely determined on every rational number (the same logic applied to multiplication).